# Why Facebook Canvas over Facebook Page Tab?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas

I have read up on the differences from 'setting' up the Canvas Page vs the Page Tab. I also see the Canvas page allows for interaction with notifications, bookmarks, newsfeed, timeline etc. However, doesn't a Page Tab also allow that?

I am trying to figure out in what instances would you use a Canvas over a Page Tab.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference between apps embedded into pages and canvas apps that is the canvas apps have their own, unique URL under the https://apps.facebook.com/... domain.

The fact your app is embedded on a page or not is not necessarily in your hand because the app creator and page admins could be different people. The added integration points facebook gives you all tied to this URL. (I guess they could use your backend url directly but they wont be able to show ads there.)

You might want to choose canvas app if you need one or more of these features:

1. #### You want to use facebook platform features tied to canvas.

   1. [requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/)
   2. [bookmarks](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#bookmarks)
   3. [apps / games dashboard](https://www.facebook.com/games)
   4. show up in [search](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#search) results
2. #### Want to support wide screens

   Canvas pages [can be configured](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fluidcanvas/) to expand "wall-to-wall" and take advantage of users with big screens.
3. #### Want to use deep links (easily) into your app.

   Deep links can be implemented on page tabs with the `data` GET parameter (coming down into your app via [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) on tabs), but canvas pages get this for "free".

There's a [best practice](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/canvas/) guide in docs on how to create good canvas apps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Everything makes sense for the Canvas app. I have actually created a few canvas apps. However, some of the projects I have been working on do not seem to warrant it. I have been thinking of using Page Tab apps and integrating the website via an iFrame but just want to see if there are other disadvantages to Page Tabs. I would only need to know if they like the tab or not and some basic facebook info (email, gender etc).

Comment: Checking for like with signed_request or with user_likes permission doesn't differ much, and for the Graph API, there's no difference. However adding canvas page and rendering the same exact content shouldn't really add too much to a project (this is what i usually end up doing).

Comment: @complex857 You said that "deep links on canvas pages get it for free", in what way or how can it be done?

Comment: @Jhn, on canvas pages, the urls look like this: `https://apps.facebook.com/<namespace>/<other_segments>?query=string` The `<other_segments>` and query string will be passed down to your callback url as-is. So if your bakend is like `http://foo.com/` then `apps.facebook.com/fooapp/some_segment?foo=bar` will became: `foo.com/some_segment?foo=bar`

Comment: @complex857 I have here canvass page url which is this one --https://apps.facebook.com/<namespace>, I tried to render the page on this url -- /places/<placeId>. Which results to https://apps.facebook.com/<namespace>/places/<placeId>, right? It always throws a 404 (page not found) error on facebook canvas.